# Проблемы с виртуализацией в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет! Есть проблема, которую не могу решить самостоятельно и решил попросить помощи у сообщества. В проекте использую вот такой шаблон:

```
<Style x:Key="EventsListStyle" TargetType="ListView" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseEventsListStyle}">
<Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True" />
<Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Standard" />
<Setter Property="ItemTemplateSelector" Value="{x:Static listItems:ListItemsDataTemplateSelector.Instance}" />
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer>
               <ItemsPresenter />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Все работает прекрасно. Контрол который использует данный шаблон растянут по высоте и ширине на весь экран. Появилась необходимость реализовать на странице с данным контролом футер и чтобы он находился внутри скроллбара. Ниже попробую в коде показать что мне нужно:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <ItemsPresenter />
                <TextBlock Text="Footer"/> - тут вместо текстблока в проекте вью с контентом
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
```

Но при данном подходе ломатеся виртуализация. Забыл сказать, что ListBox содержит большое количество записей и начинает жутко тормозить если ее выключить. Контент довольно разношерстный, поэтому использую Standard Mode. Может быть кто-то решал такую проблему? Спасибо за ответы.